# Recycler view is loading wrong data or data from wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I'm using Recycler View to display a list of countdown timers, and each timer is shown in a Card View. But some contents of the cards are changed after the scrolling the Recycler View down and scrolling back up, as shown in the two screenshots below. The contents in the red is changed after scrolling.

Initially,when recycler view is loaded for first time is shows correct info as follows:
[image: Correct Output]

But after scrolling down and up the same cards show wrong info as follows:
[image: Wrong output]

I am loading data using JSON object request in main activity as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
String showUrl = "http://192.168.56.1/GetData.php";
private List<information> info;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    info = new ArrayList<>();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     //Cardlayout code
    createJSON();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
    myadapter adapter = new myadapter(info);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private void createJSON()
{
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Singelton.instantinate().getRequestqueue();                     

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()                                                 
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                   parseJSONResponse(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()                                                         
            {....});
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}



private void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response)
{

    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("students");
        for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int a = jsonObject.getInt("Year");
            int b = jsonObject.getInt("Month");
            int c = jsonObject.getInt("Day");
            int d = jsonObject.getInt("Hours");
            int e = jsonObject.getInt("Minutes");
            String mid = jsonObject.getString("Movieid");           
            int sesa=jsonObject.getInt("ses");             
            info.add(new information(a, b - 1, c, d, e,mid,sesa));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My recycler view adapter is as follows

```
public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.myviewholder>
{
public static int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
List<information> info;

Singelton singelton = Singelton.instantinate();
ImageLoader imageLoader = singelton.getImageLoader();
String x;


myadapter(List<information> info)
{
    this.info = info;

}

@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardcontent, parent, false);
    myviewholder pvh = new myviewholder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myviewholder holder, final int position)
{
    information in = info.get(position);
    holder.to = in;
    Calendar targetdate = Calendar.getInstance();                     //start of timer code

    targetdate.set(in.a, in.b, in.c, in.d, in.e);
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    final long diff = targetdate.getTimeInMillis() - currentDate.getTimeInMillis();
    new CountDownTimer(diff, 1)
    {        //will change every 1ms i.e 0.001 seconds

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            long diffSec = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
            long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
            long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
            long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
            long hours = (secondsDay / 3600);
            long countmilliforsec = millisUntilFinished % 1000;
            long milliseconds = countmilliforsec % (SECONDS_IN_A_DAY);
            holder.textView1.setText(days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes \n" + seconds + " secs " + String.format("%03d", milliseconds) + " millisconds " + "remaining ");
            holder.textView3.setText("Position" + position);    //Dispalying the position here
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {

            holder.textView1.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();             //end of timer code



}
 public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{...}
```

What am I doing wrong.I know that the onBindViewHolder is called each time I scroll up,but then why am I receiving the wrong position?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating timers for each view try creating one timer that will refresh whole `RecyclerView` by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This way you will keep things in sync.

Comment: How to do that.Sorry I am new to android.Can you please point me to the resources that will help me in achieving it.